# Rank property of a matrix including symmetric and persymmetric Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

I am investigating the property of the [Hankel Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) recently. Here, I have a question, what is the rank property of $[\mathbf{S}\ \mathbf{P}]$, where $\mathbf{S}$ is a symmetric hankel matrix and $\mathbf{P}$ is a [persymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix) hankel matrix (both equal)?

P.S. I try to search the papers but all discussing Toeplitz plus Hankel matrix. I could not find any paper about this problem. I find that this matrix is full rank or rank one (all the elements are equal to a constant). Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are exactly $S,P$ ?; are they square ?  A square Hankel matrix is symmetric. On the other hand, what is your definition of persymmetric ? (symmetric wrt. the false diagonal or Hankel ? cf. wiki). Rewrite your question specifying the dimensions.

Comment: @loupblanc I am sorry that I did not explain explicitly. Two matrices are both square. What's more, the definition of persymmetric matrix means that the matrix is symmetric about its anti-diagonal line. (wrt. to the first def. in the link of the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $S=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$; then the $3\times 6$ matrix $[SP]$ has rank $2$.

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, I read your answer. But I was busy at that time and I did not give you response. Very sorry